# Css JQuery not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have this JavaScript code that works fine on all browsers and IE11, except IE8 where the image doesn't appear at all.
It adds an image background on the div with class="validation" that it inside the `div with id="firstpassword"`  :

```
$('#firstpassword').find('.validation').css('background-image', 'url(../../Content/img/noicon.png)');
```

Comment: is it proper path to image that you try to set?

Comment: Which version of Jquery as support for IE8 was dropped in the 2.x versions?

Comment: What amout return this query in console : `$('#firstpassword').find('.validation').length` ?

Comment: does the div.validation have a declared width and height? it may be there but not wide/high enough to see it

Comment: The path of the image is correct. The div.validation has a declared width and height that woks fine on other browsers.

Comment: What kind of image are try to display? Since IE8 has sometimes trouble with PNG itself and often with PNG and transparency.

Answer (score 0):

You missing the quotes inside the brackets of url..

`$('#firstpassword').find('.validation').css('background-image', 'url("../../Content/img/noicon.png")');`

Comment: It's the same even with the quotes . I dont know what else to do it doesn't work in IE8